# Unnecessary white area at ScrollView bottom beyond its child content, in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui-scrollview

I have a scroll view just like that.

```
public var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    BannerView
                        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.30)
                    SignInContent
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Before adding the `scrollview`, everything was fine except the screen is not able to scroll. But after I put inside a scrollview. The white area appear. `Spacer()` can't help pushing from inside to bottom. Below screenshot, ZStack is highlighted which is inside the `scrollview`. I also find a way to change background color of scrollview but can't. The only solution i found yet is to add `.padding(.bottom)` to the lowest view of `SignInContent` but I don't think it's a proper way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the height of `BannerView` to 0.3 of the screen height. So I guess `SignInContent` has the black background. But if the height of `SignInContent` is not as much as 0.7 of the screen height then the background will run out.

A `Spacer` inside a `ScrollView` will have no effect, so maybe this is why the height of `SignInContent` is less than it was before the `ScrollView` was put around it. Even setting `frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` will have no effect.

To fix, you could move the background to the `ScrollView`:

```swift
ScrollView {
    // content as before
}
.background(.black)
```

Alternatively, you could set the minimum height of `SignInContent` to the remainder of the screen height. Here, it would be better to use a `GeometryReader` to read the height of the screen, instead of using `UIScreen.main.bounds`, which is deprecated. However, if the height is increased after the background is applied, then the background won't grow. So you need to do it the other way around and apply the background after increasing the height:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    ScrollView {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                BannerView
                    .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 0.30)
                SignInContent
                    .frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height * 0.7, alignment: .top)
                    .background(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
```

You wouldn't have to apply the background again if `SignInContent`  was implemented as a `ZStack` with the background color as one of the layers:

```swift
var signInContent: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        Color.black

        // The other content here
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView {

            // somewhere inside ScrollView
            signInContent
                .frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height * 0.7)
        }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that .frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height * 0.7) is not working and I don't know why. But the second solution of changing scrollview background is working. But I think there should be a proper way. Let me wait other comments for a day before I approve your answer. And thanks for GeometryReader things. I changed my code.

Comment: @ZinWinHtet Yes, I updated the answer with a note about why it wasn't working and a way to get it working. The order of modifiers is important.

Comment: You're right. I set the background color inside SignInContent. Now it's working fine by setting minHeight of 0.7.

Comment: + another way to work around the problem, by using a ```ZStack``` for SignInContent

Comment: inside SignInContent is ZStack. I wrapped everything inside it with ZStack from the beginning.

Comment: In that case you could try setting the background color as the first layer in the ```ZStack```, instead of applying the color as ```.background``` (see code in answer). Then the color should grow automatically when the height is increased.

Comment: that was the same i did too.